# How to speed up adding data to a sorted WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid and I programatically set the ItemsSource to a list of data containing 600 rows.

A package of data arrives from my web service. I process it and update the list of data one row at a time. The grid updates in less than a second.

If I click a grid column and sort the grid, processing the package and updating the list can take minutes.

I need to figure out how to speed this up.

It looked like the sorting was slowing down the data refresh so I tried to clear the sort before loading that data by doing the following:

```
 ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(KernGrid.ItemsSource);
 dataView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
 dataView.Refresh();
```

It did not make any difference.

I also tried disconnecting the list of data from the grid, updating it then re-connecting (by pointing the grid at another blank list then pointing it back at the live list) but that made no difference either.

Any ideas?

Comment: General but interesting question. If you remove updating, load the grid and sort, is it still slow?

Comment: See the links: [Insertion Sort Algorithm](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.ru/2011/07/sort-any-collection-by-certain-property.html), [Improving DataGrid sorting performance. Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/08/26/improving-microsoft-datagrid-ctp-sorting-performance.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/08/28/improving-microsoft-datagrid-ctp-sorting-performance-part-2.aspx)